# How to create jmeter script using existing jmeter scripts

Tags: jmeter

New to jmeter and I would like to build scenario by calling existing  jmeter scripts.

I first created the external script as follows:

Test Plan
 Test Fragment
  Thread group
  Test scripts (http request for web services)

Then I created a master script, that had a number of include controllers and a module controller.

Test plan
 Thread group
  Include controller (calls existing jmeter script)
 Module controller

Comment: show what's not working

Comment: Please explain your issue in detail. You are not understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get used to look at *jmeter.log* file - normally it contains all the necessary information allowing to get to the bottom of the issue.

A couple of "blind shot" guesses:

1. First of all check whether you can run "external" script standalone (without [Include Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller) or [Module Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller)). If you can - update your question with your Test Plan configuration and *jmeter.log* file contents.
2. If you cannot - it might be due to JMeter versions mismatch, i.e. "external script" is created using [JMeter 3.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-3.3) or higher
3. Another possible reason: "External script" relies on plugin(s) which is(are) missing in your JMeter setup. Identify which test elements are absent and install them using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/).